# Make a background disappear on user input. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have this code:

```
<input style="background: src(mybackgroundimage.png) no-repeat right" type="text">
```

How can I make the background disappear if a user inputs something into the textbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732848/make-input-field-background-image-disappear-after-text-is-inputted?rq=1

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian I want to use JavaScript, CSS or HTML and not JQUERY

Comment: i have updated my answer can you check with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput) event:

```
// Assuming: <input class="inp" id="inp" type="text">
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (this.value) {
        this.style.background = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```

Note: IE9+.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3kaR/

If you need ie support you can do something like this:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
inp.addEventListener('change', clearBackground, false);
inp.addEventListener('paste', clearBackground, false);
inp.addEventListener('keyup', clearBackground, false);

function clearBackground() {
    this.style.background = 'none';
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3kaR/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input style="background: src(mybackgroundimage.png) no-repeat right" type="text" onchange="bg(this)">

<script>
    function bg(obj) { obj.style.background = "none"; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the input for keyboard activity and switch the background styles:

```
<input type="text" style="background: green"  onkeyup="modifyBackground(this)">

function modifyBackground(elem){
    if( elem.value !== "" ){
        elem.style.background = "gray";
    } else {
        elem.style.background = "green";
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sag6Y/1/)

Or using jQuery:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
        $(this).css('background','gray');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background','green');
    }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

This will properly reset the background when emptied again, and will trigger the function on page load so it will auto set its default color.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sag6Y/)

Comment: I want to use HTML, CSS or JavaScript not Jquery

Comment: Added non-jQuery example

Answer (score 0):

Since this still comes up on google, I'd like to point out that with HTML 5 you can use the **placeholder** attribute with an input to achieve this in one piece of html.

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" placeholder="search..." />
```

Placeholder is now standard across modern browsers, so this really would be the preferred method.

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name"
       onfocus="(this.value == 'Enter Your Name') && (this.value = '')"
       onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Enter Your Name')" />
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBpFV/2/)

Comment: However, `placeholder` changes the text, not the `style` property.

Comment: @BotskoNet i have updated my answer you can check with it now

Comment: My point was, he's asking about changing the background style of th input, not it's value, when the user enters text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
function disappearImg(inputElem){
    inputElem.style.backgroundImage= "none";
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="disappearImg(this)" style="background: src(mybackgroundimage.png) no-repeat right">
```